# Improve Numeric regex to not match empty dot

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to match a number:

`^[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*(E[+-]?[0-9]*)?$`

Shown here: https://regex101.com/r/aAosEj/1. However, this also matches the empty dot, `.`. Is there a simple way to improve this regex for that, or do I need to handle the case in two ways, one which does `num?.num` and another which does `num.?`

Comment: More bad news: the empty string matches and a naked "E" matches too.  The naked E can be fixed by changing your last "*" to a "+" since a naked exponent is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing too simple here, but not too bad...

You need two cases, digits+ (. digits*)? OR . digits+
You also need to fix the exponent, which must be present if the E is used.

```
^[+-]?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)(E[+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```